# How to generate random String of numbers?

Tags: java, string, random, integer, java-stream

I need to generate a `String` of random ints, and I could use a loop

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        String pageReferenceString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            pageReferenceString += String.valueOf(r.nextInt(9));
        }
        System.out.println(pageReferenceString);
    }
}
```

But, it seems too complicated, I could also have used streams

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class StreamRandomNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        String pageReferenceString = IntStream
            .generate(() -> r.nextInt(9))
            .limit(100)
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            .reduce((a, b) -> a+b) // a.concat(b)
            .get();
        System.out.println(pageReferenceString);
    }
}
```

But it is still too complicated.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: The string length is 100

Comment: Your first example could use a `StringBuilder` but that's a nit.  How is the first example "too complicated"?  Put the code in a method and the rest of your code can generate a random `String` of digits with one method call.

Comment: `String pageReferenceString = new Random().ints(100, '0', '9' + 1) .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `java.math.BigInteger` to represent a 100-decimal digit number to string:

```
String s = new java.math.BigInteger(336,new Random()).toString().substring(0,100);
System.out.println(s.length() + " : " + s);
```

Produces:

```
100 : 3627584459248992174732353013411646520422611738128940010551544228607987109715317481157384457047726562
```

336 is the number of bits required to ensure a 100-digit number and account for a "missing" leading 0.

Comment: This would be what I am looking for, but sometimes it produces `strings` of length `101`.

Comment: hence the `substring` portion - did you include that?

Comment: Oh, missed that :)

Comment: Updated to 336 - if one assumes a leading 0 not rendered then need an extra 3 bits (from 333).  See : https://planetcalc.com/8985/?num=99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the stream as follows:

```
    String pageReferenceString = Stream
            .generate(() -> String.valueOf(r.nextInt(9)))
            .limit(100)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
```